# Sorting PHP echo output by time posted

Tags: php, sql, css, html

Ok, so. I have asked about 5 questions on stackOverflow today, you've all been so helpful.

Now, i'm a designer, learning to code, so bear with me.

I have a mySQL table, with a small CMS/Blog im building.
I have it styled how I want to now.
This is the code for the page.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<h1>" . $row['Title'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h2>" . "Posted on:   " . $row['Date'] . "</h2>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['Image']."'/>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['Message'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I'm still working on it so its all good.

What I want to know is, this code is outputting my sql data into a page. Is there any way of telling the page what order to echo the data, for instance. in my SQL table i have:

```
2012-11-03 16:16:06     This is my First Blog Post  This is the first message of the first blog post. ...   http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/201.
```

and next is

```
2012-11-03 16:17:29     This is my Second Blog Post     This is the second message of the Second Post, You...   http://www.aviation-images.com/user/zooms/118/451n...
```

How can i tell the page to Always display the most recent post at the top, and older ones below.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` in your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog ORDER BY Date DESC");
```

Comment: I could kiss you GBD :) Kudos.!

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL database schema uses [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/datetime.html) for the `Date` column, you can simply sort in the MySQL query with [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog ORDER BY Date DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto-increment column like `post_id`, then you can use `ORDER BY post_id DESC` as well. :)